# Configure web.config for different scenarios

Tags: asp.net, web-config, settings

I have a few projects where we have 3-5 different web.config.xxx that should meet different scenarios, developer-computer, build-server, test-server, production-server, production-internal, production-external. The xxx is just a marker describing the environment to which it belongs.

These web.configs are mostly identical, things like connectionsstrings, integrationpoints, mailserver etc are different but the structure are more or less identical. So if I add a value in the web.config, I have to write it down into a couple of files, if I change the value I have to change it in all web.configs in the solution... It is very easy to think that I will do this later, I might change the name, I'm not sure if this is right.. so we miss values when we come to production sometimes, and that is embarrasing. The problem is that this is a problem that should be easy to eliminate.

How to handle this situation? I'm starting to look at "pre-build-events" that could check the build-configuration and do some simple replacements, change {db} to DevDB if I'm building in debug. If I build for build-server I could have a build-configuration and make the suitable replacement for that environment.

Is there a prefered way of handling this?

Comment: are you using Web Site projects or Web Application projects? If you are using Web Application projects, those specific web.config.xxx won't be useful to you since they don't get merged during build or re-build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you would benefit from config transformations.

> When you deploy a Web site, you often want some settings in the deployed application's Web.config file to be different from the development Web.config file. For example, you might want to disable debug options and change connection strings so that they point to different databases.

The source below illustrates how to configure a web.config transform file that is applied automatically during deployment in order to make changes to the web.config.

Source: [How to: Transform Web.config When Deploying a Web Application Project](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465318.aspx)

Note: This technique may be applied to any number of deployments (Staging, Testing, Production, Foo, Bar, etc).

Typically, in a project, you would have 1 web.config file.  Associated with that you might have web.production.config, web.staging.config, etc.  Each of the web.*.config files would be a transformation that contains a little bit of language for modifying various values in your web.config, such as connection strings.  Each of those transformation files is associated with a deployment option that you would ordinarily select during deployment (the little dropdown at the top of Visual Studio that is usually set to 'Debug').

Comment: Unfortunally we are working with websites... your solutions where exactly what I was looking for in every aspect but that one...